# how to create a one-dimensional dynamic array in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, dynamic

noob question on c#: how to create a one-dimensional dynamic array? And how to change it later?

thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of using an array, you can use the `List<>` object in C#.

```
List<int> integerList = new List<int>();
```

To iterate on items contained in the list, use the `foreach` operator :

```
foreach(int i in integerList)
{
    // do stuff with i
}
```

You can add items in the list object with `Add()` and `Remove()` functions.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    integerList.Add(i);
}

integerList.Remove(6);
integerList.Remove(7);
```

You can convert a `List<T>` to an array using the `ToArray()` function :

```
int[] integerArray = integerList.ToArray();
```

Here is the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) on `List<>` object.

Comment: I would add that if you need an array as output, you can then call .ToArray() on your list after you have finished processing it.

Comment: Make sure `using System.Linq` is included for Paddy's idea to work.

Comment: @Callum : Linq is not required to use the ToArray function.

Comment: Oops, sorry, my mistake. It is for IEnumerable<T> though.

Comment: Not even, I'm working and .Net 2.0 and I can use IEnumerable<T> and ToArray()

Answer (score 3):

Sure sounds like you should look into `List<T>` instead.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, a `List<T>` is likely what you want. But for completeness, you can resize an array using the `Array.Resize` static method. Example:

```
int[] array = { 1, 2, 3 };
Array.Resize(ref array, 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

use either:

```
ArrayList  //really you should avoid this.
or List<T>
```

so

```
var my_list = new List<Your_List_Type_Here>() (Like List<String>);
```

This way to add you just do:

```
my_list.Add(Your_Object);
```

Link to Generic List:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx

if you want to go back to an array then just call the [ToArray()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x303t819.aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are not dynamic. If you want something dynamic use a ['List<T>'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) or some other collection. You can always call the [ToArray()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x303t819(v=VS.100).aspx) method on it to get an array back.